# Vue&TypeScript: how to avoid error TS2345 when import implemented in TypeScript component outside of project directory?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, typescript-decorator, typescript-definitions

I got below TypeScript error when tried to use side component (outside of project directory):

```js
TS2345: Argument of type '{ template: string; components: { SimpleCheckbox: typeof SimpleCheckbox; }; }' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'VueClass<Vue>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'template' does not exist in type 
'VueClass<Vue>'.
```

My WebStorm IDE did not detect this error; in was outputted in console when I ran Webpack with TypeScript loader.

The error occurs in:

```js
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import template from './SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.pug';
import SimpleCheckbox from './../../../../ui-kit-libary-in-development/UiComponents/Checkboxes/MaterialDesign/SimpleCheckbox.vue';


@Component({ template, components: { SimpleCheckbox } }) // here !
export default class SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly text!: string;
}
```

As follows from `ui-kit-libary-in-development` name, this is not npm-dependency yet, so it is not inside `node_modules` for now.

It was exclusively TypeScript error; although `ts-loader` casts this error, Webpack builds my project and compiled JavaScript works correctly. This error will disappear if to do one of below actions:

- Move `SimpleCheckbox.vue` to same directory as `SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts` and import it as `import SimpleCheckbox from './SimpleCheckbox.vue';`
- Remove `SimpleCheckbox` from `@Component({ template, components: { SimpleCheckbox } })` and leave only `@Component({ template, components: {} })` (off course, `SimpleCheckbox` will no be rendered in this case, but it proves that problem is not in `SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel`).
- Move `ui-kit-libary-in-development` to `node_modules` of main project and  remove `node_modules` from `ui-kit-libary-in-development` (if don't remove, nothing will change).

Unfortunately, I could not reproduce this problem. For some reason below try of reproduction works without errors:

**MainProject/src/Application.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
  PageOne
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import PageOne from './PageComponents/PageOne'

  @Component({ components: { PageOne }})
  export default class Application extends Vue {
    private created(): void {
      console.log('Done.');
    }
  }
</script>
```

**MainProject/src/PageComponents/PageOne.ts**

```js
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import template from './PageOne.pug';
import Button from './../../../UiKitLibraryStillInDevelopment/UiComponents/Buttons/Button.vue';


@Component({ template, components: { Button } })
export default class SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel extends Vue {}
```

**MainProject/src/PageComponents/PageOne.pug**

```
.RootElement
  Button(:text="'Click me'")
```

**ui-kit-libary-in-development/UiComponents/Buttons/Button.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
  button {{ text }}
</template>


<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component
  export default class SimpleCheckbox extends Vue {
    @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly text!: string;

    private created(): void {
      console.log('OK!');
      console.log(this.$props);
    }
  }
</script>
```

All clues what I found is this comment in issue [Setting components in Component decorator causes Typescript 2.4 error](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/123):

> Side components should add .d.ts for it to work AFAIK.
>
> [Nick Messing](https://github.com/nickmessing)

From this clue, the following question arising:

- Where I should to create `.d.ts` - in my main project or dependency? Most likely in main project, but if it so, why I can import side components in third-party libraries like `vuetify`? Because there is `.d.ts` there!
- How I need to declare new Vue component in `.d.ts`? Some tutorial or example?

---

### Source files for bounty

Because I could not reproduce this problem and my project still is raw (has not got commercial value yet), I can share it by Google Drive ([link for downloading zip archive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MWCBc1jppZcvRfh0622f69CtU8Sf5WFO/view)). All `node_modules` are included, just run `npm run developmentBuild` in `main-project` directory.

If you are worry about potential viruses, you can also get source files in [this repository](https://github.com/TokugawaTakesi/questions-can_not_import_type_script_component_from_outer_project), but because it is does not include `node_modules`, for reproducing it's required to execute `npm install` in both `main-project` and `dependency` directories.

Comment: *" was outputted in console when I ran Webpack with TypeScript loader."* how do you run it? what is the command and at what folder?

Comment: @acdcjunior, directory: "path/where/you/unzipped/**main-project**", command: `npm run developmentBuild`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has become quite a long answer. If you don't have time to read it all there's a **TL;DR at the end**.

---

## Analysis

### Error Message

At first I didn't really understand why TypeScript mentioning `VueClass<Vue>` and complaining about the `template` property. However, when I looked at the type definitions for the `Component` decorator, things became a bit clearer:

[`vue-class-component/lib/index.d.ts`](https://unpkg.com/browse/vue-class-component@7.1.0/lib/index.d.ts) (parts omitted)

```js
declare function Component<V extends Vue>(options: ComponentOptions<V> & ThisType<V>): <VC extends VueClass<V>>(target: VC) => VC;
// ...
declare function Component<VC extends VueClass<Vue>>(target: VC): VC;
```

What we can see here is that `Component` has two signatures. The first one to be used like you did, and the second one without options (`@Component class Foo`).

Apparently the compiler thinks our usage doesn't match the first signature so it must be the second one. Therefore we end up with an error message with `VueClass<Vue>`.

> **Note:** In the latest version (3.6.3), TypeScript will actually display a better error, stating both overloads and why they don't match.

### Better Error Message

The next thing I did was temporarily comment out the second function declaration in `main-project/node_modules/vue-class-component` and sure enough we get a different error message. The new message spans 63 lines so I figured it wouldn't make sense to include it in this post as a whole.

```
ERROR in /tmp/main-project/InitializeProjectGUI__assets/SingletonComponents/SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel/SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts
../InitializeProjectGUI__assets/SingletonComponents/SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel/SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /tmp/main-project/InitializeProjectGUI__assets/SingletonComponents/SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel/SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts(10,24)
      TS2322: Type '{ SimpleCheckbox: typeof SimpleCheckbox; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: VueConstructor<Vue> | FunctionalComponentOptions<any, PropsDefinition<any>> | ComponentOptions<never, any, any, any, any, Record<string, any>> | AsyncComponentPromise<any, any, any, any> | AsyncComponentFactory<...>; }'.
  Property 'SimpleCheckbox' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'typeof SimpleCheckbox' is not assignable to type 'VueConstructor<Vue> | FunctionalComponentOptions<any, PropsDefinition<any>> | ComponentOptions<never, any, any, any, any, Record<string, any>> | AsyncComponentPromise<any, any, any, any> | AsyncComponentFactory<...>'.
      Type 'typeof SimpleCheckbox' is not assignable to type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'.
        Types of property 'extend' are incompatible.
          Type '{ <Data, Methods, Computed, PropNames extends string = never>(options?: import("/tmp/dependency/node_modules/vue/types/options").ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<import("/tmp/depende...' is not assignable to type '{ <Data, Methods, Computed, PropNames extends string = never>(options?: import("/tmp/main-project/node_modules/vue/types/options").ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<import("/tmp/main-...'.
            ...
              Type 'import("/tmp/dependency/node_modules/vue/types/vnode").ScopedSlotReturnValue' is not assignable to type 'import("/tmp/main-project/node_modules/vue/types/vnode").ScopedSlotReturnValue'.
                Type 'VNode' is not assignable to type 'ScopedSlotReturnValue'.
```

As you can see the error message is quite hard to read and doesn't really point to a specific problem. So instead I went ahead and started reducing the complexity of the project in order to understand the issue better.

### Minimal Example

I'll spare you the whole process which involved lots of trial and error. Let's jump directly to the result.

#### Structure

```
├─ main-project
│  ├─ node_modules // installed packages listed below (without sub-dependencies)
│  │     ts-loader@6.1.0
│  │     typescript@3.6.3
│  │     vue@2.6.10
│  │     vue-property-decorator@8.2.2
│  │     vuex@3.1.1
│  │     webpack@4.40.2
│  │     webpack-cli@3.3.9
│  ├─ SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
│  └─ webpack.config.js
└─ dependency
   ├─ node_modules // installed packages listed below (without sub-dependencies)
   │     vue@2.6.10
   └─ SimpleCheckbox.ts
```

#### `main-project/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

#### `main-project/webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    }
};
```

#### `main-project/SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts`:

```
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import 'vuex';

import SimpleCheckbox from '../dependency/SimpleCheckbox';

Component({ template: '', components: { SimpleCheckbox } });
```

#### `dependency/SimpleCheckbox.ts`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default class SimpleCheckbox extends Vue {}
```

When running this example from `main-project` with `npm run webpack`, we get the exact same error as before. Mission accomplished.

### What's Happening?

While I was removing parts of the project to get it down to this minimal example, I learned something very interesting.

You might have noticed the `import 'vuex'` I've added to `SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts`. In the original project `vuex` is of course imported from different places (e.g. `main-project/Source/ProjectInitializer/Store/Store.ts`) but that's not important for reproducing the issue. The crucial part is that **`main-project` imports `vuex` and `dependency` doesn't**.

To find out why importing `vuex` causes this issue, we have to look at the type definitions of `vuex`.

[`vuex/types/index.d.ts`](https://unpkg.com/browse/vuex@3.1.1/types/index.d.ts) (first few lines)

```js
import _Vue, { WatchOptions } from "vue";

// augment typings of Vue.js
import "./vue";

import { mapState, mapMutations, mapGetters, mapActions, createNamespacedHelpers } from "./helpers";
```

Here we are interested in the second `import`. The comment actually gives us a hint already: *augment typings of Vue.js*.

[`vuex/types/vue.d.ts`](https://unpkg.com/browse/vuex@3.1.1/types/vue.d.ts) (parts omitted)

```js
import { Store } from "./index";

// ...

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $store: Store<any>;
  }
}
```

And here we have the culprit. The `vuex` types make use of [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add `$store` to the `Vue` interface of `vue`. It seems that this augmentation only happens to "local" types in the same `node_modules` as `vuex`. Because `main-project` has the augmented `Vue` and `dependency` has the original one, the two don't match.

### TS Loader

During all my testing I couldn't reproduce the problem with just `tsc`. Apparently `ts-loader` does something differently causing this issue. It could have to do with it using Webpack for module resolution or it could be something entirely different. I don't know.

## Solution Approaches

I have some ideas how this problem could be solved or worked around. Although these are not necessarily ready-to-use solutions but rather different approaches and ideas.

### Add `vuex` to `dependency`

As removing `vuex` from `main-project` isn't really an option, the only thing we can do to make both `Vue` interfaces match, is include `vuex` in `dependency` as well.

The odd thing here is that I was able to get this fix working in my minimal example but not in the original project. I haven't figured out why that is.

In addition to that, it's not very elegant and you might have to import `vuex` from every file that you reference from `main-project`.

### Use a shared `node_modules`

Having a shared `node_modules` folder means both projects use the same `vue` so this problem goes away. Depending on your requirements it might be a good solution to organize the two projects in a way that they share the same `node_modules` folder. You might also want to take a look at tools like [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) or [Yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) which can help with this.

### Consume `dependency` as a package

You say that `dependency` *is not [an] npm-dependency yet*. Maybe it's time to make it one. Similarly to a shared `node_modules` directory this would result in both projects using the same `vue` installation which should fix the issue.

### Investigate further

As mentioned before, this only happens with `ts-loader`. *Maybe* there is something that can be fixed or configured in `ts-loader` to avoid this problem.

## TL;DR

`main-project` imports `vuex` while `dependency` doesn't. `vuex` augments the `Vue` interface using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) adding a `$store` property to it. Now the `Vue` from one project doesn't match `Vue` from other causing an error.

Comment: Your answer pretends to dissertation. Very deep research; my current knowledge was not enough for this. Just "thank you" will not be enough for this, but unfortunately my bounty ends without winner. I believe Mr. Cavanaugh gives you the reputation prize.

Answer (score 0):

As @lukasgeiter said,

> Apparently ts-loader does something differently causing this issue.

Error will disappear, if delegate Type Check process to [fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin).