# Bind vuex state and mutations to checkbox component properties in TypeScript-based Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

### Problem

Create the checkbox as Vue component, herewith:

1. No logic inside checkbox component allowed: all event handlers and also `checked` property are fully depends on external logic, which could be the `vuex` store.
2. We should not watch the checkbox "checked" state: checked it or not, it depends on, again, external logic, e. g. `vuex` state or getter.

---

### Try 1

#### Concept

The checkbox component has `checked` and `onClick` properties, which value are off course, could be dynamic.

#### Component

Template in [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) language:

```
label.SvgCheckbox-LabelAsWrapper(:class="rootElementCssClass" @click.prevent="onClick")
  input.SvgCheckbox-InvisibleAuthenticCheckbox(
    type="checkbox"
    :checked="checked"
    :disabled="disabled"
  )
  svg(viewbox='0 0 24 24').SvgCheckbox-SvgCanvas
    path(
      v-if="!checked"
      d='M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3M19,5V19H5V5H19Z'
    ).SvgCheckbox-SvgPath.SvgCheckbox-SvgPath__Unchecked
    path(
      v-else
      d='M10,17L5,12L6.41,10.58L10,14.17L17.59,6.58L19,8M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3Z'
    ).SvgCheckbox-SvgPath.SvgCheckbox-SvgPath__Checked
  span(v-if="text").SvgCheckbox-AppendedText {{ text }}
```

```js
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class SimpleCheckbox extends Vue {

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, required: true }) private readonly checked!: boolean;

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false }) private readonly disabled!: boolean;

  @Prop({ type: String }) private readonly text?: string;
  @Prop({ type: String }) private readonly parentElementCssClass?: string;

  @Prop({ type: Function, default: () => {} }) private readonly onClick!: () => void;
}
```

#### Store module

```js
import { VuexModule, Module, Mutation } from "vuex-module-decorators";
import store, { StoreModuleNames } from "@Store/Store";


@Module({ name: StoreModuleNames.example, store, dynamic: true, namespaced: true })
export default class ExampleStoreModule extends VuexModule {

  private _doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag: boolean = true;

  public get doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag(): boolean {
    return this._doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag;
  }

  @Mutation
  public toggleDoNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag(): void {
    this._doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag = !this._doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag;
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
SimpleCheckbox(
  :checked="relatedStoreModule.doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag"
  :onClick="relatedStoreModule.toggleDoNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag"
  parentElementCssClass="RegularCheckbox"
)
```

```js
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { getModule } from "vuex-module-decorators";
import ExampleStoreModule from "@Store/modules/ExampleStoreModule";
import template from "@Templates/ExampleTemplate.pug";
import SimpleCheckbox from "@Components/Checkboxes/MaterialDesign/SimpleCheckbox.vue";

@Component({ components: { SimpleCheckbox } })
export default class MarkupPreProcessingSettings extends Vue {
  private readonly relatedStoreModule: ExampleStoreModule = getModule(ExampleStoreModule);
}
```

### Warings

Appears if click the checkbox. Checkbox works as we need, but some of Vue concept has been violated.

[image]

```
vue.common.dev.js:630 [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <SimpleCheckbox> at hikari-frontend/UiComponents/Checkboxes/MaterialDesign/SimpleCheckbox.vue
       <MarkupPreProcessingSettings>
         <Application> at ProjectInitializer/ElectronRendererProcess/RootComponent.vue
           <Root>

vue.common.dev.js:630 [Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.

found in

---> <SimpleCheckbox> at hikari-frontend/UiComponents/Checkboxes/MaterialDesign/SimpleCheckbox.vue
       <MarkupPreProcessingSettings>
         <Application> at ProjectInitializer/ElectronRendererProcess/RootComponent.vue
           <Root>

vue.common.dev.js:630 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "checked"

found in

---> <SimpleCheckbox> at hikari-frontend/UiComponents/Checkboxes/MaterialDesign/SimpleCheckbox.vue
       <MarkupPreProcessingSettings>
         <Application> at ProjectInitializer/ElectronRendererProcess/RootComponent.vue
           <Root>
```

#### Musings

This warning are being emitted frequent cause is new value to some vue-property has been assign inside component. Explicitly, I did not the manipulations like this.

The problem is in `:onClick="relatedStoreModule.toggleDoNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag"`. It looks like it compiles to something like `<component>.$props.onClick="<vuex store manipulations ...>"` - if it so, it is implicit property mutation inside component.

### Try 2

#### Concept

Based [Vue documentation, Customizing Component section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html):

```js
Vue.component('base-checkbox', {
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    checked: Boolean
  },
  template: `
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      v-bind:checked="checked"
      v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
    >
  `
})
```

The equivalent for TypeScript with [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) will be:

```js
import { Vue, Component, Model } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
  @Model('change', { type: Boolean }) readonly checked!: boolean
}
```

##### Component

```
label.SvgCheckbox-LabelAsWrapper(:class="rootElementCssClass")
  input.SvgCheckbox-InvisibleAuthenticCheckbox(
    type="checkbox"
    :checked="checked"
    :disabled="disabled"
    @change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
  )
  svg(viewbox='0 0 24 24').SvgCheckbox-SvgCanvas
    // ...
```

```js
import { Vue, Component, Prop, Model } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class SimpleCheckbox extends Vue {

  @Model('change', { type: Boolean }) readonly checked!: boolean;

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false }) private readonly disabled!: boolean;

  @Prop({ type: String }) private readonly text?: string;
  @Prop({ type: String }) private readonly rootElementCssClass?: string;
}
```

#### Usage

```
SimpleCheckbox(
  v-model="doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag"
  rootElementCssClass="RegularCheckbox"
)
```

In TypeScript, to use the `v-model`, we need to declare getter and same-name setter:

```js
@Component({
  template,
  components: {
    SimpleCheckbox,
    // ...
  }
})
export default class MarkupPreProcessingSettings extends Vue {

  private readonly relatedStoreModule: MarkupPreProcessingSettingsStoreModule =
      getModule(MarkupPreProcessingSettingsStoreModule);
  //...
  private get doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag(): boolean {
    return this.relatedStoreModule.doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag;
  }

  private set doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag(_newValue: boolean) {
    this.relatedStoreModule.toggleDoNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag();
  }
}
```

#### Warnings

Same errors set:

[image]

#### Limitations

First, we need to create new getter and setter in Vue Component class. It will be cool if possible to avoid id. Unfortunately, for vuex class (by [vuex-module-decorators](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators)), TypeScript setters are not available, we need use the `@Mutation`-decorated method instead.

Also, this solution will not work for elements rendered by `v-for`. It make this solution useless.

### Try 3

#### Concept

Event emitter and custom event listener usage. This solution also works properly, but Vue emits warnings.

#### Component

```
label.SvgCheckbox-LabelAsWrapper(:class="rootElementCssClass" @click.prevent="$emit('toggled')")
  // ...
```

#### Usage

```
SimpleCheckbox(
  :checked="relatedStoreModule.doNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag"
  @toggled="relatedStoreModule.toggleDoNotPreProcessMarkupEntryPointsFlag"
  rootElementCssClass="RegularCheckbox"
)
```

#### Warnings

[image]

---

### Update

There are some riddles left yet, however problem has been solved. See my answer below.

Comment: `label.SvgCheckbox-LabelAsWrapper` - What is this thing? If you are using external libraries, maybe tag them and mention them in question.

Comment: @MatJ, it is the [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), the pre-processing language. Please use [this tool](https://pughtml.com/) if you are not familiar with Pug to get pre-processed HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warnings occurred in Electron application. The `SimpleCheckbox` is from `node_modules`, however this library is still in development, so it has been provided by `npm link`.

When I tried to make reproduction, I created the SPA for browser and place `SimpleCheckbox` to same project (did not get from `node_modules`). The first solution works! (I don't care about second and third ones - I need refined from peel elegant solutions only).

I suggested that cause is `npm link`, publish my libraries and installed it via `npm install`. The warnings has disappeared!

### Conclusion

It was not the first time when `npm link` causes the problem like this. Here is [another case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355411/vuetypescript-how-to-avoid-error-ts2345-when-import-implemented-in-typescript).

I still does not understand this this case in depth - I just published some experimental data. The "So, what if library is in development yet?" question still has not answer. I tried [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) - at the first time warnings has disappeared, but when I move my project to Lerna, the warnings appears again - the regularity is unclear yet for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is typescript-based issue.

According to your warning messages and your codes, I can notice that you used `prop` as a `input` model.

In default, `prop` is not allowed to be mutated.

It could be a bad idea to mutate `prop` even though it is an `Object` or `Array`. ( if prop is `Object` or `Array`, it can be mutated in children. but It is not recommended)

To avoid this warnings, you can use data which is a clone of prop in the children like below:

```
props: {
  checked: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  change: {
    type: Function,
    default: () => {},
  }
},
data: {
  checkedModel: false,
},
mounted() {
  this.checkedModel = this.checked; // init model value as prop
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, it does not work with both `<input :checked="checkedModel" />` and `<input v-model="checkedModel" />`.